# Dropdown blocked by background image

Tags: html, css

i wanted to make a dropdown in my navbar, but its always blocked by the background image from the style. The position is set to absolute, because if i set it to relative, the height of the navbar increases as well. I want it to look more or less like w3's tutorial on dropdows https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_fixed

This is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400&display=swap html_test2.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="Yearbook">
        <meta name="keywords" content="yearbook">
        <meta name="author" content="Gerald">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <style>
    
            body{
                margin: 0px;
                background: linear-gradient(45deg, #5fd5f3, #ffddc6);
                  background-size: 500% 1000%;
                  animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
            }
                @keyframes gradient {
                    0% {
                        background-position-x: 0%;
                    }
                    50% {
                        background-position-x: 100%;
                    }
                    100% {
                        background-position-x: 0%;
                        }
                    }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a>Contacts</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Person 1</li>
                        <li>Person 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a>Home</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>test 1</li>
                        <li>test 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

This is the css code

```
.navbar ul {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    }


.navbar ul li {
    transition: 0.2s;
    float: right;
    margin: 0.7%;
    }

.navbar ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 7px 25px;
    color: #252525;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 23px;
    }

.navbar ul:hover li {
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: blur(2px);
    }

.navbar ul li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0px);
    }

.navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    }

.navbar ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header image may be blocking your dropdown element due to the dropdown being "behind" the image on the "z" axis. You could try adding the z-index CSS property to your dropdown at a an arbitrary number that will bring it "above" the image, similar to how "send to back" or "send to front" works in common editing programs. The CSS for z-index is as follows:

```
img {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that property to each element, and made sure that it is larger than any other indexes, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. I deducted that it wasn't the background at fault but more of the navbar itself. Can you help me further?

Comment: Edit: I found that the problem lies in the 
`ul:hover li {
 filter: blur(2px)
}

ul li:hover {
 filter: blur(0px)
}
`
i solved it by replacing it with 
`
.navbar ul:hover li:not(li:hover) {
    filter: blur(2px);
    }
`
that seems to work in w3 editor, but not in my context, the dropdown float does not appear at all. any suggestions?